# Laravel, PHP - error while returning a view

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I applied a search field inside my master blade , using auto complete plugin of TypeAhead .

My routes :

```
Route::get('search',array('as'=>'search','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@search'));
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@autocomplete'));
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
class AutoCompleteController extends MainController {

      public function search()
    {
        return view('master');
    }

     public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {

if( !empty(request('query'))){
        $data = Product::select("title")
        ->where("title","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
->get();
     $dataJson =$data->toJson();
        return view('master', compact('dataJson'));
}else{ 

   return view ('master');
}

    }
}
```

My Master blade:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@if (!empty($title) )
        {{ $title }}  
        @else
        MySite
        @endif</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('carousel.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script>var BASE_URL = "{{ url('')}}/";</script>  


</head>

<header>
    <!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/')}}">MyHero</a>

                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                                @if( !empty($menu))
                                @foreach($menu as $item)
                                <li><a href="{{ url($item['url'])}}">{{ $item['link'] }}</a></li>
                                @endforeach
                                @endif

                                <li><a href="{{ url('shop')}}">Shop</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('shop/checkout')}}">
                                        <img width="20" src="{{ asset('images/shopping-cart.png')}}">  
                                        <div id="total-cart">
                                            @if(! Cart::isEmpty())
                                            {{Cart::getTotalQuantity()}}
                                            @endif
                                        </div>

                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>  

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                @if(Session::has('user_id'))
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/edit')}}">{{ Session::get('user_name') }}</a></li>  
                                @if( Session::has('is_admin'))
                                <li><a href="{{ url('cms/dashboard')}}">CMS DASHBOARD</a></li>  
                                @endif
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
                                @else
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signin')}}">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signup')}}">Sign Up</a></li>  

                                @endif
                            </ul>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <form method="GET" action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="find" class="typeahead form-control" aria-label="Search here..." placeholder="Search here..." autocomplete="off" value="">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="height: 34px; width: 40px" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>




</header>  <br><br><br><br>


 @if($dataJson)
    @foreach(json_decode($dataJson, true) as $value)
       {{ $value['record1']['record 2'] }}   
    @endforeach
@endif

<div class="container" >@yield('carousel')</div> <br><br>

<main>  
    <div class="container">

        @include ('inc.sm')
        @include ('inc.errors')


        @yield('content')  

    </div>

</main>  
<br><br><br>
<footer>  
    <div class="container">  
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" >
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px;" >MyHero &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>    



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

The error I get is `Undefined variable: dataJson` in my master blade view when trying to return search result from the search field.

I tried to do dd() and print_r but its not responding. The error I get is `Undefined variable: dataJson` in my master blade view when trying to return search result from the search field.

I tried to do dd() and print_r but its not responding .

Comment: Where are you trying to do inside your 
public function autocomplete(Request $request) { } ?

That $request won't contain anything

Comment: I didn't understand your question , sorry . Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: What is the value of $request->input('query') ?

Comment: It should include whatever the user typed inside the search field

Comment: Try dd($request->input('query')); in first line of autocomplete method. See what you get.

Comment: you mean before I start the if  ?

Comment: anyway the dd() is not responding

Comment: change that to dd('justrandom');

Comment: dd('justrandom'); not responding either

Comment: Show the form where user inputs the string, that is to be tested

Comment: my form is in my master blade

Comment: <form method="GET" action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="find" class="typeahead form-control" aria-label="Search here..." placeholder="Search here..." autocomplete="off" value="">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="height: 34px; width: 40px" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>

Answer (score -1):

First idea is to return variable, even if it is null or empty.   (on controller)

```
else { return view ('master', ['dataJson' => false]);
```

But I think its better to check if the variable is empty on your blade tamplate

```
 @if(!empty($dataJson))
```

Comment: I got another error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) " in my master blade view."  I do have @endif

Answer (score -1):

Change `@if($dataJson)` to `@if(isset($dataJson))`

For more information; check here: [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Now I got another error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) " in my master blade view." And I do have @endif

Comment: @SherLocked Does it say what line?

Comment: Not exactly, it says "in c8b1f4540e0eacfb9a43e3fc107c6a88db708eac.php (line 150)" . I have 148 lines in my master blade

Comment: Try clearing the compiled views from `storage/views` and then recompile, I can't find any missing `@endif` in your code

Comment: How do I do that? btw It says that the folder contains files with errors

Comment: iirc, they are compiled on run time. Where does it say that the folder contains files with errors?

Comment: there is only one file with red error icon on it when I click on it its showing me my master blade page and again the red error icon on line 150 unexpected: END of File

Comment: I'm not sure then this is very weird to me and could possibly do with a different question being asked

Comment: I am not sure either what the error related to. What kind of question should I ask?

Comment: Something like "<error here> with Laravel/Blade line 150 when my code only has 148 lines"

Comment: So I fixed that error it was my bad, just some syntax mistake, the page is displayed now but it still not shoeing me the search results. Any idea how I can fix it?